# Is this kind of cylinder bevel possible in Blender?

Tags: bevel

.blend file attached:
[image]

- Scale is 1
- Clamp unchecked in modifier
- Normals recalculated outside
- Doublet vertex merged.

**It is not doubled bevel like second screen could suggest :-) (.blend is ok)**

I added two photos with description below.

Is this kind of bevel even possible in Blender?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it's doable with the Bevel modifier, but you can easily do it without

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, you are perceptive.
It is not, this second screen was made before the first on copy, .blend file is ok. I noticed double bevel and checked it again.

Comment: is it ok if you do it without the modifier?

Comment: @moonboots No, second screen shows the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's doable with the *Bevel* modifier. If you don't care about doing it without it, you can do it this way:

Create your cube, bevel the top and bottom:

[image]

Create a vertical loopcut, bevel:

[image]

Cut a hole:

[image]

Extrude inwards, right click > *LoopTools > Circle* and set the *Influence* at 50%:

[image]

Extrude on X and *LoopTools > Circle* again, this time with an *Influence* of 100%:

[image]

Bevel the angle that you want to keep sharp:

[image]